# Checking for palindromic triangular squares in Python

Tags: python-3.x, math

```
nm = 0
def infinity(start=0):
    n = start
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 1
while nm in infinity(1):
    nT = nm*(nm+1)/2
    nS = nm**2
    nR = int(str(nm)[::-1])
    if nT==nS==nR:
        N = nT
        print(N)
    nm = nm+1
```

i've been trying to write a program that checks each number from 0 to infinity if it meets 3 requirements. Those are to be palindromic,triangular and square at the same time. i am having a hard time figuring out how to fix the mathematical part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is the overall logic. You look at each positive integer, trying to decide if it is triangular and square and a palindrome.

However, you are not really checking to see if `nm` is a triangular number or a square. You are actually calculating the `nm`th triangular number and the `nm`th square number. Except for the first ones, `0` and `1`, they are never equal to each other or to `nm`, so your tests fail. You should instead check if `nm` is a triangular number and if `nm` is a square number. Those tests are more difficult for very large values of `nm`, and I recommend a different approach.

Your palindrome check also fails. You correctly find the number that is the reversal of `nm`, but you should check that against `nm`. Instead, you check it against the `nm`th triangular and square numbers.

All those problems could be fixed, but your program would then be *extremely* slow. [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number#Numerical_data) shows the first 12 square-triangular numbers. The last one has 16 digits. Except for the first two, namely `0` and `1`, none is a palindrome. There may be palindromes up higher, but your program would take practically forever to find them.

I recommend a different approach. Use a much faster method to loop through the square triangular numbers, avoiding all the other numbers. The Wikipedia page gives several methods. Then check each of those if it is a palindrome. Python can handle larger numbers, though the calculations will become slower, so you may actually find a palindrome.

Here is a simple way to loop through just the square triangular numbers, skipping over `0` and `1` which are trivial.

```
nold = 0
n = 1
for nm in infinity(2):
    nold, n = n, 34 * n - nold + 2
    # check if n is a palindrome
```

This is an infinite loop, of course. Note that `nm` is never actually used, but it is the index of the square triangular number `n`. The calculation comes from the first recurrence relation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number#Recurrence_relations). An explanation involves the solution of Pell's equation, which usually uses continued fractions. Let me know if you really need more information on that, though the Wikipedia article does explain that more.

Answer (score 0):

There is [very simple recurrence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareTriangularNumber.html) for generating square triangular numbers. So you can generate only these numbers without wasting time to checking all naturals.

The only thing you have to do - check whether number is palindrom

```
def SqTr():
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(10):
        a, b = 2 + 34 * a - b, a
        print(a)

SqTr()
```